# Difference between "optional chaining" and "optional call chaining" in Swift

Tags: swift, terminology

Is there any semantic difference between "optional chaining" and "optional call chaining" in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provisionally I'll answer No, there is no semantic difference.

"Optional Chaining" is discussed extensively in "The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2 Prerelease), both in its own section (Optional Chaining) and in later discussions on protocols and types. I don't see "Optional Call Chaining" in that book.

Googling "optional call chaining" returns this question, so I'm not sure in what context "optional call chaining" occurs.

Comment: Thx.  It was in my notes so maybe I heard it somewhere, or made it up without realizing.

Comment: "Optional call chaining " not in programming language.